# How can you find the number of HPZ in a zone plate?

Tags: optics, diffraction

If you know what the primary focal length, and the wavelength of the light how can you find the total number of half period zones ?

Answer (score 1):

Take the path-length from the focal point to the edge of the zone plate, $\sqrt(f^2+r^2)$ and subtract the path-length from the focal point to the center of the zone plate, $f$, then divide the result by the half-wave-length of the light, $\lambda/2$. 
$N = [\sqrt(f^2+r^2)-f]/(\lambda/2)$

Comment: @Peter you will need some more information about the geometry.  Do you have any other info?

Comment: @Peter assuming that the zone-plate is 50% efficient, it means the area of the zone-plate is 2000 time larger than the area of the focused spot.  The radius of the focussed spot is of the order of f x lambda/r.  So the ratio of areas is roughly r^2/(f x lambda/r)^2 = 2000 and you can solve for r.  But look up 'Airy disk' to get the exact formula.